# Sub Report's sub doesn't print or show

Tags: crystal-reports, subreports

I have 2 reports - both of which have sub reports, and I need to combine into 1, with the main one showing then the 2nd one on a new page.

I have put the 2nd one as a subreport of the first, in the report footer. and linked accordingly.

When I preview - the main report is fine and shows it's subreport data; Then the 2nd report shows - but doesn't show it's subreport. In Fact - if I 'edit report' - the subreport element has disappeared.

First thought was that I had somehow deleted it - but no tried several times; reloaded etc etc and always happens. I ca load both separately and with same params work fine - add the 2nd to 1st and its sub disappears.

Any ideas?

Phil

Comment: I'm not sure if I got that right, but you can't have a subreport in a subreport.

Comment: Yes - I have Report 1 with sub report 1a; Plus report 2 with sub report 2a. I have put Report 2 as a subreport into the footer of report 1. When I preview I see the details from Report 1 and its sub report 1a, also see the data in report 2 - but NOT the 2a.    In design mode when I EDIT rep2 - the 2a sub has gone. Run them as separate reports and they are fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a subreport ina  subreport. Once you put report 2 as a subreport of report 1, subreport 2a will not work. You can easily try that by creating a report with a subreport, then in the subreport the option to add a subreport will not be available. That's probably why your subreport 2a disappears as soon as you add report 2 as a subreport to report 1.